# Google Distance Matrix API only returns single result

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm using Google Distance Matrix API and noticed that the API only returns a single result.
But on google map, the search offers us route choices.
How do I do to get more results on the return of the API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Gare+de+Montparnasse+2+-+Pasteur,+Place+des+Cinq+Martyrs+du+Lyc%C3%A9e+Buffon,+75015+Paris,+France&destinations=85+Quai+d%27Orsay,+75007+Paris,+France&mode=driving

[**image description**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qzG3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Distance Matrix doesn't provide route alternatives.  If you are looking for route alternatives between a single origin/destination pair, use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) with the [`alternatives` parameter set to `true`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Gare+de+Montparnasse+2+-+Pasteur,+Place+des+Cinq+Martyrs+du+Lyc%C3%A9e+Buffon,+75015+Paris,+France&destination=85+Quai+d%27Orsay,+75007+Paris,+France&mode=driving&alternatives=true
```